# How to define a mathematical function in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

I've been trying this now for hours. I think I don't understand a basic concept, that's why I couldn't answer this question to myself so far.

What I'm trying is to implement a simple mathematical function, like this:

```
f(x) = x**2 + 1
```

After that I want to derive that function.

I've defined the symbol and function with:

```
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
f = sympy.Function('f')(x)
```

Now I'm struggling with defining the equation to this function `f(x)`. Something like `f.exp("x**2 + 1")` is not working.

I also wonder how I could get a print out to the console of this function after it's finally defined.

Comment: i think you want lambdas? i am not familiar with sympy though.

Comment: I would love to use lambdas, but the task says, that I have to solve this with sympy.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `f = x**2 + 1`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`sympy.Function` is for undefined functions. Like if `f = Function('f')` then `f(x)` remains unevaluated in expressions.

If you want an actual function (like if you do `f(1)` it evaluates `x**2 + 1` at `x=1`, you can use a Python function

```
def f(x):
    return x**2 + 1
```

Then `f(Symbol('x'))` will give a symbolic `x**2 + 1` and `f(1)` will give `2`.

Or you can assign the expression to a variable

```
f = x**2 + 1
```

and use that. If you want to substitute `x` for a value, use `subs`, like

```
f.subs(x, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Do you still need to do `f = Function('f')` before defining the function or is that implicit from the python function definition?

Comment: @Bill `def f(...)` sets the variable `f` to be the Python function defined by the def. If you do `f = Function('f')`, that will override the variable `f` to be the SymPy object `Function('f')`. The two options I show here do not use `Function` at all. That is only if you want something that is completely unevaluated. See also the section [in the SymPy tutorial](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#symbols) on symbols.

Answer (score 20):

Here's your solution:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> x = sympy.symbols('x')
>>> f = x**2 + 1
>>> sympy.diff(f, x)
2*x
```

Comment: For what is sympy.Function uses, when not for defining functions?

Comment: I suppose it's a base class for a whole range of standard functions.

Comment: @Robin `sympy.Function` is for undefined functions. Like if  `f = Function('f')` then `f(x)` remains unevaluated in expressions.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility (`isympy` command prompt):

```
>>> type(x)
<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
>>> f = Lambda(x, x**2)
>>> f
     2
x ↦ x 
>>> f(3)
9
```

Calculating the derivative works like that:

```
>>> g = Lambda(x, diff(f(x), x))
>>> g
x ↦ 2x
>>> g(3)
6
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to:
[Sympy how to define variables for functions, integrals and polynomials](https://math-linux.com/python-50/sympy/article/sympy-how-to-define-variable-for-functions-integrals-and-polynomials)

You can define it according to ways:

- a python function with def as describe above
- a python expression g=x**2 + 1

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Undefined Function:

`from sympy import *`
`f = symbols("f", cls=Function)`

Answer (score -2):

I recommended :

1. first, define a symbolic variable

```html
x = sympy.symbols('x')
```

2. second, define a symbolic function

```html
f = sympy.Function('f')(x)
```

3. define a formula

```html
 f = x**x+1
```

if you have so many variable can use this function

```html
 def symbols_builder(arg):
     globals()[arg]=sp.symbols(str(arg))
```

if you have so many functions can use this function

```html
def func_build(name, *args):
    globals()[name]=sp.Function(str(name))(args)
```

Comment: At step 3 you reassign variable f, meaning step 2 effect is lost. And actually step 2 is not needed, step 3 is enough.