# Why does my lambdify not working when add my own function

Tags: python, sympy

I created a function and make it usable in my Sympy expression like this:

```
  def Unit(x):
        if(x != 0):
            return 0
        else:
            return 1
  Unit = Function('Unit')
  x = Symbol('x')
```

My expression:

```
fx = x ** 2 + Unit(x)
```

But when I run:

```
lam_f = lambdify(x, fx, modules=["sympy"])
print(lam_f(-1))
```

It said that my Unit is not defined?
Can anyone explain where i went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`Function('Unit')` returns an undefined function with name `Unit`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100053/how-to-define-a-mathematical-function-in-sympy). If you want to use your previously defined function `Unit`, remove the call to `Function()`:

```py
def Unit(x):
    if(x != 0):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

x = Symbol('x')
fx = x**2 + Unit(x)

lam_f = lambdify(x, fx, modules=['sympy'])
print(lam_f(-1)) # prints 1
```

Comment: when I use simpify() function with fx it returns 1 whereas I want it to return my full expression.