# Multi Parameter Function Replacement with Sympy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I've got a math equation that I want to visually record the substitution of.

The equation is y = h * f(t + h, h + f(t, h)), where f(x, y) = x + y - 1
I want to substitute f into y, such that I get:
y = h * f(t + h, h + (t + h - 1))
y = h * (t + h + h + (t + h - 1) - 1)

I've had issues with replace not allowing me to do multi-parameter substitution

I don't have much code, since I'm not sure how to implement it

```
from sympy import *

f = Function('f')(x, y)
eqn = h * f(t + h, h + f(t, h))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sympy.Function is used for [declaring undefined functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37122871/827519) but in your case the function is known.

The following code seems to work fine over here

```py
from sympy import *
x,y,t,h = symbols('x y t h')

def f(x,y):
    return x + y - 1

y = h * f(t+h,h+f(t,h))
y = expand(y)

display(y)
```

The role of the [expand function](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#expand) was to work out the outer multiplication by h in the definition of y.

You can run it in a [Jupyter notebook](https://jupyter.org/) or as an alternative use [the print or display function](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html), I get the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Extending average's answer -- Their solution works perfectly if the function is known.

To make it work for a function that's input from the user, you need to do this:

```
function = input()
def f(x, y, evaluate = False):
    eqn = sympify(function)
    if evaluate:
        eqn = eqn.subs([("x", x), ("y", y)])
    return eqn

y = h + f(h, t, True)
```

This way, if the user inputs "x ** y" for f, y will expand to h + h ** t